# how to press button with same id but in different class?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium webdriver to click on a button in a different class. The webpage is as follows:

```html
<div class="fade tab-pane" id="mm9-tab-content" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="button-submit">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block post" id="download" type="button">Download</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fade tab-pane" id="dm3-tab-content" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="button-submit">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block post" id="download" type="button">Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the data is in 2 classes `mm9-tab-content` and `dm3-tab-content`. I want the system to click on the download button in the `dm3-tab-content`.

I tried using

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath = (//*@id="download")[1]').click()
```

to get the second instance of `download` but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: try find_element_by_css('#dm3-tab-content #download')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath seem to be invalid. Try below instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="download"])[2]').click()
```

Note that, unlike in Python, in XPath nodes indexation starts from `1`, so the second element should have index `[2]`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order in which the buttons appear and which one you want to use, you could find all the elements with the id="download", using `find_elements_by_css_selector`:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#download')
```

Then, you can access each button in order.

Answer (score 0):

To click the button under mm9-tab-content class use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mm9-tab-content #download').click()
```

To click the button under dm3-tab-content class use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dm3-tab-content #download').click()
```